# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: NG] Error while reading JPA XML file: META-INF/SQLQueries.xml

Tags: sql, hibernate, persistence, jpa-2.0, persistence.xml

I have tried several suggested methods to resolve this java persistence exception but have not been successful yet. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Below are the details

```
SQLQueries.xml
-----------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd "
    version="2.0">

    <sql-query name="GET_NEXT_NUM_SP" callable="true">
        <return alias = "nextNumber" class="com.utility.numbergenerator.da.NumberDAOImpl">
        <return-property name="nextSeqNum" column="NEXT_SEQ_NUM" />
    </return>
        { ? = call Test_Proc }
    </sql-query>    

</entity-mappings>
```

---

```
persistence.xml
-----------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NG" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/SQLQueries.xml</mapping-file>
        <class> Several related classes </class>
        <properties> Followed by properties </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

### Stack trace of the exception

> -- Initializing database connection --
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: NG] Error while reading JPA XML file: META-INF/SQLQueries.xml
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1205)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1004)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:282)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:366)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
>       at com.go2uti.oneworld.common.hibernate.HibernateUtil.initializeJPA(HibernateUtil.java:68)
>       at com.go2uti.oneworld.common.hibernate.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:38)
>       at com.go2uti.oneworld.utility.businessidgenerator.da.EntityManagerFactorySingleton.init(EntityManagerFactorySingleton.java:26)
>       at com.go2uti.oneworld.utility.businessidgenerator.compatibility.AbstractPersistentTest.initializeContext(AbstractPersistentTest.java:38)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
>       at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:101)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:513)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:509)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:716)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:801)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addResource(AnnotationConfiguration.java:152)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1192)
>       ... 34 more

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `META-INF/SQLQueries.xml` file is based on JPA 2.0 XML mapping schema which is defined by http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd.

Since `sql-query` element is Hibernate specific you need to replace `<entity-mappings>` with `<hibernate-mapping>` as shown below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>

    <sql-query name="GET_NEXT_NUM_SP" callable="true">
        <return alias="nextNumber" class="com.utility.numbergenerator.da.NumberDAOImpl">
            <return-property name="nextSeqNum" column="NEXT_SEQ_NUM" />
        </return>
        { ? = call Test_Proc }
    </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```